# "com.dsi.ant.plugins.antplus.pcc does not exist" error for ANT+ in Android Studio 2.1.3

Tags: android-studio, garmin

I am trying to use the [runnerup project](https://github.com/jonasoreland/runnerup) but I get the below error. My Android Studio is 2.1.3:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you do not have the correct `ant+` library

For the runner up project you need to make sure that you have the code pointing towards the `correct .jar` file.  In this case I do not think it is picking up the `../ANT-Android-SDKs/ANT+_Android_SDK/API/antpluginlib_3-1-0.jar` in your hrdevice `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    provided files('libs/samsung_ble_sdk_200.jar')
    compile files('../ANT-Android-SDKs/ANT+_Android_SDK/API/antpluginlib_3-1-0.jar')
```

Answer (score 2):

I am adding one more thing, I have faced same problem and fixed by downloading below source code via below github link and placed on **ANT-Android-SDKs** folder (if folder is empty).

https://github.com/ant-wireless/ANT-Android-SDKs/tree/c35bcf8ee9b6379e405693dbd6bec506ec533669